# echo value is different when that variable is passed in php

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-java-bridge

I was working in php java bridge and came across this problem.
The below is the code

```
 $payID     =  $epaymentpipe->getPaymentId();

 echo $payID;
```

the expected value is printed e.g., 5323423123

but when i pass the same variable in header like below, the object id is passing in payID.

```
header("location: URL?PaymentID=".$payID);
```

**it is passing like http://URL?PaymentID=Object id #53**

I Need to know whats happening here. When the variable is echoed its printing correctly but when i use the variable the object id is passing.

Comment: Can you post the entire code?

Comment: What does `var_dump($payID)` give you?

Comment: var_dump($payID) gives me the object array

Comment: Look at the documentation if the object specifically has a method for returning the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("location: URL?PaymentID=".$payID);
```

Use

```
header("location: URL?PaymentID=".((string)$payID));
```

and report this bug to the PHP developers.

The . operator should convert its arguments to a string using $object->__toString().

**Note that this has been fixed in PHP 5.3 and above!**

Answer (score 1):

Cast the object as a string:

```
$payID = (string)$epaymentpipe->getPaymentId();
header("location: URL?PaymentID=".$payID);
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of echo is different as of that of print_r and var_dump, whenever any such thing happens check the value by dumping it through print_r or var_dump.

Comment: i check it by var_dump a long object array in printing